# Crear un nuevo atributo desde un método dentro de la clase?

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

Continuando con el ejercicio anterior, ahora se requiere implementar el sueldo
     a pagar a cada profesor, por lo que se debe agregar el atributo correspondiente y
     un método que permita agregar el valor para dicho atributo. Siguiendo en cosideración
     que: si tiene más de 10 años de experiencia se le asignará 3000, de 5 a 10 años 
     2500 y menos de 5 años 2000. Actualizar los métodos para que el sueldo del profesor
     se muestre junto con sus demás datos.

```
Class Profesor{
var $nombre;
var $direccion;
var $experiencia;
var $asignatura;
var $anhos;

public function __construct($nombre, $direccion, $experiencia, $asignatura, $anhos){
    $this->nombre = $nombre;
    $this->direccion = $direccion;
    $this->experiencia = $experiencia;
    $this->asignatura = $asignatura;
    $this->anhos = $anhos;
}

public function get_nombre(){
    return $this->nombre;
}

public function set_nombre($x){
    $this->nombre = $x;
}

public function get_direccion(){
    return $this->direccion;
}

public function set_direccion($x){
    $this->direccion = $x;
}

public function get_experiencia(){
    return $this->experiencia;
}

public function set_experiencia($x){
    $this->experiencia = $x;
}

public function get_asignatura(){
    return $this->asignatura;
}

public function set_asignatura($x){
    $this->asignatura = $x;
}

public function get_anhos(){
    return $this->anhos;
}

public function set_anhos($x){
    $this->anhos = $x;
}

function salario(){
    if($anhos < 5){
        $salario = 2000;
    }else if($anhos > 5 && $anhos <= 10){
        $salario = 2500;
    }else{
        $salario = 3000;
    }
    return $salario;
}

}
```

Bien, en el ejercicio anterior he creado una clase con ciertos atributos. Según este ejercicio debo agregar un nuevo atributo (A lo que he añadido anhos) para conocer cuánto es su salario. Pero lo que me deja a cuadros es la parte final "Actualizar los métodos para que el sueldo del profesor se muestre junto con sus demás datos".
¿Esto quiere decir que debo crear una función para que reproduzca "salario" como nuevo atributo sin haberlo declarado en el constructor?
Y si es así ¿cómo podría hacer eso?

Perdonad pero estoy un poco verde con esto de la POO

Mil gracias

Comment: Basicamente te pide un método y un atributo, un método para determinar el valor y un atributo para almacenar dicho valor. No obstante, no acostumbramos a hacer los ejercicios, mas aun si no se han intentado y tampoco aportan el código mínimo. Revisa [ask].

Comment: hola @Xerif, muchas gracias por tu respuesta y disculpa mi ignorancia. Acabo de editar la consulta y agregar mi código. Entonces solo pide lo que presento??

Muchas gracias

Comment: El salario es calculado en base a los años, por tanto no tienes que recibirlo en el constructor. Sí deberías en cambio declarar un propiedad `salario` dentro de la clase. En cuanto a *"Actualizar los métodos para que el sueldo del profesor se muestre junto con sus demás datos"*, en la clase no se ve ningún método que muestre todos los datos juntos. El requerimiento no es claro, si no lo entendiste, debiste pedir clarificación al profesor cuando asignó el ejercicio. También, deberías llamar al método `get_salario` para tener uniformidad en la convención de nombres.

Comment: Muchas gracias @A.Cedano. Sí que está nada claro... :D Es bueno saber que no es mi percepción. El problema es que no es de un profesor, hago ejercicios por mi cuenta que me pasa un amigo para aprender por mi mismo. Pero esto de la POO me confunde y mucho. Además que me faltan herramientas por aprender...  Por ejemplo, al decir que debo declarar una propiedad "salario" dentro de la clase ¿cómo podría hacerlo?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Yo creo que lo que se pide es definir el atributo *salario* solamente que este, en vez de obtener su valor mediante lo que obtenga en el constructor, lo haga por medio de la función `salario()`.

Comment: Las propiedades no se *declaran* en los métodos `set`, en ellos se asignan o se modifican los valores de las propiedades, las cuales se declaran en la cabecera de la clase, tal y como declaraste `$anhos`, o sea algo así: `var $salario;` Luego, habría que ver, porque el salario se puede calcular en el mismo constructor (al menos en este caso). Y en la asignación usarías `$this->salario` como haces con las otras propiedades de la clase.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay varias cosas que corregir:

- Declara los miembros como `private` para encapsular. `var` es muy antiguo y en versiones modernas de PHP ya levanta un warning, por tanto evita usarlo
- Agrega una propiedad `salario` en la clase
- Usa `$this` en el cálculo del salario
- Usa una *convención de nombre* que sea uniforme
- Se agregó un método `get_alldata` que satisface el requerimiento *"Actualizar los métodos para que el sueldo del profesor se muestre junto con sus demás datos"*
- Se simplificó la lógica, asignando un salario mínimo de `2000`

La clase quedaría así:

```
Class Profesor{
    #Usamos private para encapsular
    private $nombre;
    private $direccion;
    private $experiencia;
    private $asignatura;
    private $anhos;
    private $salario;

    public function __construct($nombre, $direccion, $experiencia, $asignatura, $anhos){
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
        $this->direccion = $direccion;
        $this->experiencia = $experiencia;
        $this->asignatura = $asignatura;
        $this->anhos = $anhos;
    }

    public function get_nombre(){
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    public function set_nombre($x){
        $this->nombre = $x;
    }

    public function get_direccion(){
        return $this->direccion;
    }

    public function set_direccion($x){
        $this->direccion = $x;
    }

    public function get_experiencia(){
        return $this->experiencia;
    }

    public function set_experiencia($x){
        $this->experiencia = $x;
    }

    public function get_asignatura(){
        return $this->asignatura;
    }

    public function set_asignatura($x){
        $this->asignatura = $x;
    }

    public function get_anhos(){
        return $this->anhos;
    }

    public function set_anhos($x){
        $this->anhos = $x;
    }

    public function get_salario(){
        #Salario mínimo
        $this->salario=2000;

        #Usamos $this y simplificamos el salario sólo cambia en estas dos condiciones
        if($this->anhos > 10){
            $this->salario = 3000;
        }else if ($this->anhos >= 5 && $this->anhos <= 10){
            $this->salario = 2500;
        }
        return $this->salario;
    }

    public function get_alldata(){
        $data="Nombre: $this->nombre\nApellido: $this->apellido\nSalario:$this->get_salario()"; //Agregar los otros datos
        return $data;
    }

}
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias @A. Cedano
Es un placer poder aprender con gente que te apoye de este modo

:D

Comment: @A. Cedano Solo como nota, segun el ejercicio se pide utilizar la experiencia para calcular el salario, por lo que se debería utilizar dicha propiedad. Por otro lado en el contructor no se debería establecer el salario minimo de forma directa (y seguramente tampoco las otras propiedades), se debería llamar al método destinado a tal efecto para que determine el salario sea cual sea. Tal como esta el siguiente ejemplo podría dar un valor erróneo `$p = new Profesor('Cloe', 'Calle', 10, 'mates', 45);
$p->get_salario(); // 3000
$p->set_anhos(1);
echo $p->get_salario(); //3000 ¿?`.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón @Xerif. No había pensando en eso. He corregido esa parte asignando el salario mínimo en el *getter*. Gracias por la nota.